# get data after union max and min sql statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, max, union, min

Is there any way to combine these sql statements in one statement:

```
   Dim s As String = 
   "SELECT  byu,MAX(atttime) AS attime FROM att 
    WHERE pno='" + DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString + "' 
    and attdate ='" + curdate + "' and atttime>='" + mxtime + "'
    and atttime<='" + mxtime2 + "' "


  Dim xmd As New SqlCommand(s, con)
  Dim dr As SqlDataReader = xmd.ExecuteReader
  If dr.Read Then
     DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value = dr("attime")
     DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(14).Value = dr("byu")
  End If
     dr.close
   Dim s2 As String =
     "SELECT byu, MIN(atttime) AS attime FROM att 
     WHERE pno='" + DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString + "' 
    and attdate ='" + curdate + "' and atttime>='" + mintime + "'
    and atttime<='" + mintime2 + "' "
  Dim xmd2 As New SqlCommand(s2, con)
  Dim dr2 As SqlDataReader = xmd2.ExecuteReader
  If dr2.Read Then
  DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = dr2("attime")
  DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(15).Value = dr2("byu")
  End If
  dr2.Close()
```

the table att has data as:

```
  pno   attdate     atttime   byu
   2    2015/01/02  07:05:02   0 
   2    2015/01/02  07:07:02   1 
   2    2015/01/02  18:08:11   0
   2    2015/01/02  19:15:02   1
```

i was trying since morning and didn't come up with something, the problem that when i union the 2 sql statement i couldn't get the "byu" of MAX(atttime) and also the "byu" of MIN(atttime) via SqlDataReader. I almost red all the questions in the site that related to this and nothing worked for me so far.the result of above code is:

```
2     2015/01/02    07:05:02   0
2     2015/01/02    19:15:02   1
```

please help, thanks.

Comment: how you getting `byu` from this line  DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(14).Value = dr("byu") while you are only reteriving one column from database in you query

Comment: sorry , i've corrected my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can join you queries like this and execute them as a batch statement

```
Dim s As String = 
   "SELECT byu as byu1,MAX(atttime) AS attime1 FROM att 
   WHERE pno='" + DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString + "' 
   and attdate ='" + curdate + "' and atttime>='" + mxtime + "'
   and atttime<='" + mxtime2 + "' group by byu ;" +
   "SELECT byu as byu2,MIN(atttime) AS attime2 FROM att 
   WHERE pno='" + DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString + "' 
   and attdate ='" + curdate + "' and atttime>='" + mintime + "'
   and atttime<='" + mintime2 + "' group by byu ;"
```

This is the only idea i dont know how many columns you are getting from database you have to set your cells() value respective of column order which you are getting from database

```
Dim xmd As New SqlCommand(s, con)
Dim dr As SqlDataReader = xmd.ExecuteReader
  If dr.Read Then
     DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value = dr("attime1")
     DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(14).Value = dr("byu1")
     DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value = dr("attime2")
     DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(15).Value = dr("byu2")
  End If
```

Comment: sorry, i've corrected my code where i miss the select byu of both statements, can u rewrite ur code to fit my question please. am really sorry for this mistake i am sure it makes different.

Comment: what i want based to ur code, how i get the byu1 of attime1, and the byu2 of attime2.

Comment: it says invalid column name byu1!!

Comment: @OsamaGadour Sory i forget to add `byu as byu1` and `byu as byu2` i have updated my answer check it now

Comment: @OsamaGadour it sounds above suggestion work. i have Updated my code and added `group by byu` check it

Comment: sorry for bothering u, now it shows me a message box "attime2" ,the first part of the statement ,"MAX"'s part is working and shows me the result in data grid, but when it comes to MIN as i said it shows me message only says "attime2"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71936/discussion-between-khurram-ali-and-osama-gadour).